# robolectric 3.0 Mockito -- how to mock a class inside activity

Tags: mocking, robolectric, android-testing

**I am in process of migration to  robolectric 3.0**

**Problem Statement--**

I have a class AppUtility, which is instantiated inside MyActivity, so to check its methods are invoked, I need to mock it inside my test before setting up the MyActivity.

Here is my code:

```
@Mock
private AppUtility mockAppUtility;

@Before
public void setUp() {
    initMocks(this);
    myActivity= Robolectric.setupActivity(MyActivity.class);
    equalsButton = (Button) myActivity.findViewById(R.id.equals_sign);
    shadowActivity = Shadows.shadowOf(myActivity);
}
```

Here is the test method:--

```
  @Test
        public void shouldCallStartAlarm() {
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                equalsButton.performClick();
            }
            verify(mockAppUtility).startAlarm();
        }
```

Bu I get the following error msg:-- which show mock is not linked to the activity, how can I bind it to activity??

```
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.
```

But the mock object is not associated with the test. With earlier version of Robolectric  I  use to associate the mock object on activity creation, by overriding it as below

```
 myActivity = new MyActivity() {
                @Override
                AppUtility getUtil() {
                    return mockAppUtility;
                }
            };
            myActivity.onCreate(new Bundle());
```

and it use to work fine, with Robolectric 3.0 , how can I bind the mock object  before starting the activity.

Following @nenick your second option:This is how it looks

```
    @Mock
    private AppUtility appUtility;
    @InjectMocks
    private MyActivity myActivity;
    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        ActivityController<MyActivity> activityController = Robolectric.buildActivity(MyActivity.class);
//      myActivity= Robolectric.setupActivity(MyActivity.class);
        myActivity=activityController.get();
        initMocks(this);
        activityController.setup();
        equalsButton = (Button) myActivity.findViewById(R.id.equals_sign);
//      shadowActivity = Shadows.shadowOf(calculatorActivity);
    }
```

but I get fllowing exception:-

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: attempted to invoke public final android.app.Application org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowActivity.getApplication() on instance of class org.com.android.AppUtility$$EnhancerByMockitoWithCGLIB$$77c74666, but AppUtility$$EnhancerByMockitoWithCGLIB$$77c74666 doesn't extend ShadowActivity
```

> it breaks at step--activityController.setup();

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just set mock is easy with mockito mock injection feature.

```
@Mock
private AppUtility mockAppUtility;

@InjectMocks
Activity mActivity;

@Before
public void setUp() {
  myActivity= Robolectric.setupActivity(MyActivity.class);
  equalsButton = (Button) myActivity.findViewById(R.id.equals_sign);
  shadowActivity = Shadows.shadowOf(myActivity);

  // create and injects mocks into object annotated with @InjectMocks
  initMocks(this);
}
```

To set mocks before activity setup (onCreate, ...) is called you must access your activity before setup.

```
@Before
public void setUp() {
  ActivityController<Activity> activityController = Robolectric.buildActivity(Activity.class);

  // get the activity instance 
  mActivity = activityController.get()

  initMocks(this);

  // now setup your activity after mock injection
  activityController.setup()
}
```

Comment: I am updating this in my question, is it looks clumsy here.

Comment: Thanks @nenick , mock injection feature was real helpful.

Comment: Did you resolve the IllegalArgumentException? Mockito is to aggressive and replace the __robo_data__ property.

Comment: I am new to Robolectric, so actually shadowActivity did the complete work me. I mean it made the  actual object so I went with the flow. I need to get more thorough in Mockito. Thanks for your help nenick

Comment: I think shadows + mocks behavior is still to evaluate more

Answer (score 0):

One of the main rule of unit testing - never mock class under the test. You might `spy` on it but again it is rescue challenge which you should not use in this case.

Another `smell` showing that you have wake test - when you will be able to run this tests successfully it will not guarantee that real alarm set. It will guarantee only that this method was called. So it is better to verify set alrams instead of verifying method call. Check [this link](http://www.multunus.com/blog/2014/03/tdd-android-using-robolectric-part-3/) for the example use of shadow alarm manager

Comment: startAlarm() method is noway related to android alarm manager. The problem statement is:-- once the equals button is pressed four times, startAlarm() method should get a call.  So I need to test suing Mockito verify , whether it is called or not. How can I mock the utility class inside activity, any idea?

Comment: `UtilityClass` sounds like static method call. Correct? If so you you can wrap it in non static context and mock it under the test. As I mentioned you can still spy no the real class instance

Comment: sorry, but its not even static method calls. Actually, I am instantiating the class in the activity(UtilityClass name is just a reference for the problem in stackoverflow)

Comment: Watch video from Misko Hevery https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLED6CA927B41FF5BD about separation of the instantiation and usage

Comment: Thanks @Eugen,I understand your point. I am actually into a maintenance of an already existing app, developed more than a year back with eclipse, where I am not allowed to do design refactoring. The test cases were written using Robolectric 2.0-alpha release, and so my job is to port them to Robolectric 3.0.